# MongoDB query for documents with nested objects and array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having trouble with mongodb querying my object document.
I have the following document:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
"name" : "Bob", 
"fields" : {
    "DATE" : [
        {
            "fromDate" : null, 
            "values" : [
                "2022-08-01"
            ]
        }
    ]
},    
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("2"), 
"name" : "John", 
"fields" : {
    "DATE" : [
        {
            "fromDate" : null, 
            "values" : [
                "1901-08-01"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the document where **fields.date[0].values** is equal to **2022-08-01**.

How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a nested element value which having some specific value/date.
Since your document is incomplete so, I am creating one for illustrating the solution.

```
db.employees.insertMany([{ 
"name" : "Bob", 
"fields" : {
    "DATE" : [
        {
            "fromDate" : null, 
            "values" : [
                "2022-08-01"
            ]
        }
    ]
}},
{ 
"name" : "John", 
"fields" : {
    "DATE" : [
        {
            "fromDate" : null, 
            "values" : [
                "1901-08-01"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
},
{ 
"name" : "Eve", 
"fields" : {
    "DATE" : [
        {
            "fromDate" : null, 
            "values" : [
                "2022-08-01"
            ]
        }
    ]
}},
]);
```

Now we can find the specific value (2022-08-01 as per your requirement) from the nested array/element inside the document. Since the value resides inside *"DATE"* which is inside the *"fields"*. So we can get that value easily by calling  *"fields.DATE"*.
For example you can write some code like this :

```
db.employees.find({"fields.DATE":{"$elemMatch": {"values": "2022-08-01"}}})
```

From the above code you will get a result like this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62e94392389644cb3fc9c81f"), "name" : "Bob", "fields" : { "DATE" : [ { "fromDate" : null, "values" : [ "2022-08-01" ] } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62e94392389644cb3fc9c821"), "name" : "Eve", "fields" : { "DATE" : [ { "fromDate" : null, "values" : [ "2022-08-01" ] } ] } }
```

Hope this will help you to solve this issue. Happy coding:)